# Nodejs Google authentication rest api

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have rest api with node js and mongoose I want to make authentication with google if anyone can help me to answer my question

Comment: You question is way too vague man.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!